# Connecting to Redis To Go with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, redis

I am a newbie with Redis...I just recently picked up [Redisent](https://github.com/jdp/redisent) to work with Redis in PHP...and I am having tons of fun!  However, I signed up for the [Redis to go](http://redistogo.com/) service, and have been beating my head to connect to use the service...

The URI string is as follows:

> redis://[username]:[pass]@[server].redistogo.com:[port]/

The Redisent client simply takes in the hostname and the port...and there's no place for me to enter the username/password... :-/ I've been fiddling around with the fsockopen() function, too...but no score.

Has anyone tried connecting to Redis to go with PHP? If so, any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Note: I realize that there is a REST API available, but that's for provisioning instances, not for the actual operations such as GET/SET,etc.

Comment: Have you considered using a different PHP library to connect to Redis? I looked at the list on Redis to go's site and some of the others took passwords.

Comment: Thx! Sure thing, guess that's what I have to do...one reason I went with Redisent was the way it just does a pass-through of commands without renaming them.  I'll have a look at other ones and maybe could modify the connection logic in Redisent...=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) is the prefered library([active development => 6 Januari 2011](https://github.com/nrk/predis/commit/c247d6201af5d52ca1b6f79b8b4248650d02a58e)) to use.

```
redis://$x:$y@$z
```

Then you need the following code to get it working(I tested it):

```
<?php

require('./Predis.php');

#redis://$x:$y@$z
$redis   = new Predis\Client('redis://$z');
$redis->auth($y);
$redis->incr('counter');
echo $redis->get('counter');
echo "\n";
```

The strange thing is `$x`. It is not needed at all?

Comment: Great! Will test it out pronto!

Comment: Yes! I got it! Thank you so much =)

Answer (score 3):

```
$db = 1;
$password='password';
$aRedisServers['host']="127.0.0.1";
$aRedisServers['port']= "6379";
$r = new Predis_Client();
$r->connect($aRedisServers['host'], $aRedisServers['port']);
$r->auth($password);
$r->select($db);

$r->set("set","new");
echo $r->get("set");
//output new
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation now, you can do this as part of the instantiation...

```
$redis = new Predis\Client(array(
    'host'     => '10.0.0.1', 
    'password' => 'secret', 
    'database' => 10, 
));
```

or

```
$redis = new Predis\Client('redis://10.0.0.1/?password=secret&database=10');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `php-redis` to authenticate using ACL (username and password combo)

Following example works for me using AWS MemoryDB for redis.

```
$redis = new \Redis();
$redis->connect('tsl://ENDPOINT', 6379);
$redis->rawCommand("auth", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
echo $redis->set("test","2");
echo $redis->get("test");
```