# Do we need another table on this autocomplete scenario?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form that after submitting will save the data into a database.

However, that form will contain some data that will come from the database as well.

For example, an autocomplete form field functionality needs to retrieve data from the database.

1. I'm talking about 2000 records or so for that autocomplete so, perhaps it's to much for a database enum or set type on MySQL ?
2. If it is, then what should I do ? Should I create another table containing only those names that will populate our autocomplete ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I would store the [autocomplete](http://antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html)'s in in-memory(very FAST) database like for example [redis](http://redis.io) to speed things up. An easy way to probably accomplish this is by using [php-redis-autocomplete](https://github.com/rishair/php-redis-autocomplete) in conjunction with a free [redistogo](http://redistogo.com) instance. I [got redistogo working by the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918569/connecting-to-redis-to-go-with-php/4918702#4918702).

**P.S:** if possible installing(compiling) redis locally would be way better in my opinion, but almost never possible when using very cheap hosting.

Comment: Alfred, I thank you your suggestion. Unfortunately that will not be a solution since I can't compile redis on my host and, even if I did, I'm not ready to add another technological layer here.

Comment: those kinds of queries are very expensive in SQL and that's why all the big sites replace them with an in-memory solution. But if you must, then put an index on the field and query it using something like `LIKE`...

Comment: p.s: installing redis is easy and using it also