# phpredis with Redis to go

Tags: php, redis, redistogo

I got a problem similar to this one:

[Connecting to Redis To Go with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918569/connecting-to-redis-to-go-with-php)

Basically, I have this uri in redis to go:

redis://myusername:foopassword@herring.redistogo.com:9998

and I am trying to connect to it using phpredis:

$r->connect("redis://myusername:foopassword@herring.redistogo.com:9998/");

And it's not working. In that other answer it is suggested to use predis, but I just don't want to. I should be free to use whatever client I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: +1 for standing against predis; phpredis is a native extension, it's bound to be more efficient than predis even if the development is less active.

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead:

```
$r = new Redis();
$r->connect("herring.redistogo.com", 9998);
$r->auth("foopassword");
```

If that doesn't work, try `$r->auth("myusername:foopassword")` instead.

You can find the phpredis documentation on [the official GitHub page](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis).

Answer (score 0):

I have not used redistogo, but maybe you could try?

$r->connect('herring.redistogo.com', 9998);
$r->auth('myusername:foopassword');